# Conserving upto 16 decimal places in Python

Tags: python, pandas, text, decimal

I have a table of numerical in a text file with 16-digit decimal precision that I am reading into a Jupyter Notebook and converting it into a Pandas DataFrame. How can I use the decimal module with pandas to preserve the precision from the text file? Or is there anything else that would work better? Currently, it is showing only up to 5-6 decimal places. Thanks!

code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
folder = Path("C:/This/is/the/path")
file = folder1/"thisfile.txt"
df = loadtxt(file1)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The input is a text file:

```
                2                    2  -14914.622755795561     
                3                    2  -10563.365160496842     
                4                    2  -6927.2062998872152     
                5                    2  -3886.5429891705344     
                6                    2  -1370.9348975732908
```

The output looks like this in pandas:

```py
0   2.0 2.0 -14914.622756
1   3.0 2.0 -10563.365160
2   4.0 2.0 -6927.206300
3   5.0 2.0 -3886.542989
4   6.0 2.0 -1370.934898
```

Comment: can you give an example of the input & what you are getting out? Have you looked at [pandas.DataFrame.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)?

Comment: Probably the value is just not shown in full. Try `with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:0.17f}'.format):
    print(df)`

Comment: Thank you @DrBwts and @ilja! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas doesn't reduce the precision of your data, but it just rounds it off while displaying.

To get 16-digit decimal precision, set the display formatting of float to 16 digits.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.16f}'.format
```

Use the above configuration after importing pandas.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Yes, this worked pretty well: 

```python
0 2.0000000000000000 2.0000000000000000 -14,914.6227557955608063
1 3.0000000000000000 2.0000000000000000 -10,563.3651604968417814
2 4.0000000000000000 2.0000000000000000 -6,927.2062998872152093
```
Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, remember to accept the answer if it worked for you since this can help others. Thanks :)